# What is the best solution to solving nested, referenced documents?

Tags: gui-design, lists, info-visualisation

This question was a little ambiguous and I apologize for that, so here's a little context:

- You have a list of updates displayed in a table.
- Each update has an ID associated with it.
- When you click the ID, a modal panel slides in from the right.
- The modal panel includes bullet points about the updates and a ***list of Bug Report IDs*** which are fixed by that update.
- You can click on the Bug Report ID, and that pulls out another modal panel, with the details of the bug report.
- When you're finished looking over that, you can close that modal panel, the previous one is still open below it, and you can click on another Bug Report ID if you wanted more information, etc. etc.

I don't think the double modals is the best way, but I'm at a loss. I've never had to deal with this nesting issue. So the interface has a list of fixes, each fix requires a detailed view to display the multiple associated bugs, and each bug report requires a detailed view to display all of that information.

If anyone has any inspiration, or feedback, or design patterns, or anything! - It would be immensely helpful.
Thank you so much!

[image: Screen One]
[image: Screen Two]
(Screen three is exactly like screen two, except it's the information bug the bug report. It would overlay the Dependency Details, so when you close it, you can continue looking at the other Bug Reports associated with that particular update. Unfortunately, I don't have enough rep to post it.)

Edit: Just an added note, I can't do collapsible panels. Each fix has a collapsible panel that shows dependencies. :( Makes me Sad

Edit: Added some really quick examples to help illustrate what I'm talking about. It's for a company project, and they don't really want me to share screenies, but this one has been a tough cookie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree model + panel does not sound good.

**Why not continue with panels?**

There are many ways to do this, the one below assumes minor changes and retaining your layout. See example below. One option is to **retain the directional flow of content and preserve relation to the list**.

[image: Side panel flow]

Comment: This is really nice, and kind of the direction I was headed. I just posted some screen shots that align well with your concept. Could you talk about why you feel like modals (pop up in the center of your screen) are not the best way to go? I have some coworkers who are trying to go full modal, lol.

Comment: I do love the sideways panels, though. That's got that really nice scalability aspect. I think this is an awesome solution! :)

Comment: It all goes down to a consistent design pattern for a single flow. What you described is a single flow and if you use a modal and a panel - those are two different design patterns. Also a use of modal as a 3rd step takes the user out of context (modals are visually disconnected from the page)